# Allow a List to Float Left on page Report Builder 3

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I need to float a list (if anyone is familiar with HTML / CSS they will understand). I'll try to elaborate.

I am using a report to create labels to specific dimensions. I need an 8 x 2 list.

I've created my list but the list does not appear on the left and right hand side of the page, it simply renders 8 lists down the left of the page and goes onto the next page.

This can be achieved within Access 2010, you change the page layout to have two columns, this is what I need. 
I have created an image to try and explain what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML/CSS in reporting services is a little more difficult than you might expect.  Based on what you are trying to do, I'd recommend a simpler method using Report Builder's built in tools.

Put two tablixes next to each other horizontally (Lists might work the best, since the labels appear to be the same size) and link them to the same dataset.  Then under Row Groups view the Group Properties and set the Visibility expression of the left tablix to only show odd row numbers: `=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, True, False)`.  Use the same expression for Visibility on the right tablix but switch true and false around to only show even rows.